# ehcache giving error after migrating spring boot from 1.5.12 to 1.5.13

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I have configured spring boot 1.5.12 + ehcache and everything was working fine until I upgraded spring boot to 1.5.13

`application.yml` has the below entry

```
spring:
  cache:
    jcache:
      provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
      config: ehcache.xml
```

my `ehcache.xml` is located under `resources` directory

The error I am receiving is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache configuration does not exist 'ServletContext resource [/ehcache.xml]'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties.resolveConfigLocation(CacheProperties.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration.createCacheManager(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration.jCacheCacheManager(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5c3a047.CGLIB$jCacheCacheManager$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5c3a047$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a6ae7187.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5c3a047.jCacheCacheManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

It looks like spring boot has started searching for `ehcache.xml` using servletContext resolver.

p.s. I had made no change in any of source code except the spring boot upgrade to 1.5.13

Am I missing some required configuration here?

Comment: Facing the same issue upgrading from 1.5.10 to 1.5.11 or later. I believe the change happened in 1.5.11 that is breaking compatibility.

Comment: Can you share a sample we can run ourselves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had figured out the fix for this problem. We need to specify the prefix `classpath:` with the file name to make it work.

My `application.yml` would look like this now

```
spring:
   cache:
     jcache:
        provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
        config: classpath:ehcache.xml
```

Hope that helps.